# How to access backend if blocked cors policy java spring?

Tags: java, spring, cors

**I use Java spring for backend, when frontend hit my endpoint he get error**

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.100.74:9009/v1/admin/c2da6237-22d2-433a-97b7-226d1989bd99/list-user' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*

**I use Java Spring, how i can handle this? thanks**

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a `@CrossOrigin` annotation to you controller method. Please see a detailed description at https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ under the heading "Enabling CORS".

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the client domains from which you want to give access to call your APIs. For that you can simply create `CORSFilter`. Below is the minimal `CORSFilter` implementation:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.servlet.Filter#init(javax.servlet.FilterConfig)
 */
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.servlet.Filter#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
 * javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain)
 */
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // IMPORTANT: Allowed all the domains
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, HEAD");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Content-Disposition");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    httpServletResponse.addIntHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 3600);
    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(httpServletRequest.getMethod())) {
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.servlet.Filter#destroy()
 */
@Override
public void destroy() {

}
}
```

Specifically focus on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in above code.

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` this is just wrong. you should only allow it from your known origins, not from everywhere.

Comment: That is just an example to explain how we can build `CorsFilter`. I am not insisting on hardcoding `*` every time.

Comment: You can always write whatever domains you want to allow. Common man, that is very much understandable.

Comment: you are also allowing `Authorization` header as well as credentials in cross-origin requests. Why would you recommend such a thing?

Comment: I think you are not aware of `Authorization` header that's why you are speaking like that. That particular header is used to pass the authentication token. And by the way, that answer is just depicting how you can add the headers to the response. "THAT IS JUST AN EXAMPLE".

Comment: you shouldn't give bad practices as examples

Comment: Okay, sir. That's what you see the things.

Comment: @eis This platform is not for code/logic copy & paste as you want, You can get solution/code around your issue, And then you need to understand that and implement as per your project need.

Comment: @PSabuwala I agree. That does not mean you should give bad examples when you could do better.