# CORS Spring Boot and React Admin - React

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I am using "React Admin" for creating an admin interface (front end).
I am using Spring boot for my REST API.
My React app's url is : "http://localhost:3000".
My Spring boot api's url is: "http://localhost:8080".

Here is my Spring Boot code for CORS configuration, it is in a separate class called CorsConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
         registry.addMapping("/**")
         .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")  //frontend's link
         .allowedHeaders("*")
         .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Here is my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Admin,ListGuesser, Resource} from 'react-admin';
import restProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';


const parentURL = restProvider(`http://localhost:8080`);

function App() {
    return(
       <Admin dataProvider={parentURL}>
          <Resource name="DashBoard" list={ListGuesser}/>
          <Resource name="list" list={ListGuesser} />
       </Admin>
    );
}
export default App;
```

In the "Chrome DevTools", I am getting the following errors, that are complaining about the CORS policy that is configured on the backend:

**Question 1:**

[Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGDSg.png)

**Question 2:**
I am also getting the following error which is complaining about the restProvider:
[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0siz.png)

What are the possible solutions for the above 2 errors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `CORSFilter` in Spring boot as I have mentioned in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66882700/3709922

Add allowed domains in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value. `*` means allowed all domains.

Add `Content-Range` in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header value list like:

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
        "..., Content-Range");`
```