# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cors, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to solve a CORS issue with `spring data rest` but seems like the CORS headers are not attached. This is the config I have:

```
@Component
class DataRestConfig: RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    override fun configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config: RepositoryRestConfiguration?, cors: CorsRegistry?) {
        cors?.addMapping("/*")
           ?.allowedOrigins("*")
           ?.allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "DELETE","PATCH","POST","OPTIONS")
     }
}
```

I also had the same issue with other API routes that are out of spring data rest. Here is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
open class WebSecurityConfig(private val userDetailsServices: DatabaseUserDetailsServices, private val jwtService: JWTService): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("\${auth.jwt.secret}")
    private var secret: String = ""

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(JWTAuthorizationFilter(userDetailsServices, secret, jwtService),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,UserController.LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    }
}
```

Edit:

1. Added the full `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
2. I noticed that the OPTIONS request gets 403 this is why I've added the `antMatchers` for OPTIONS method but it did not help.
3. Here are the response and request headers. There is no response body:

[image]

Comment: have you checked the HTTP traffic, how is your web site responding?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant but I checked and I can see an OPTIONS request made before the GET. In the response header I can see non of the options I set for corse

Comment: please add the HTTP traffic to the question. What is the exact response for the options request? can you add your full WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? can't reproduce the problem with this information

Comment: also, please only have one question per question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My question is only about Spring Data REST. Routes outside that are working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the other configs are not taken into account and I don't know if this is considered a good solution but since I only need this on the local environment it is not that important. This is how I got this working:

```
@Bean
@Profile("local")
open fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource{
    val cors = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    val config = CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()

    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PATCH)
    config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE)

    cors.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)

    return cors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring MVC you should configure the CORS behavior like so

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the non Data REST endpoints but the rest is still missing the CORS headers

Answer (score -1):

You can always have a `CorsFilter` to modify response headers. Here I have answered how we can have custom `CorsFilter` in Spring boot - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66882700/3709922. Kindly have a look.